# How to Give Access Without Authentication To Swagger documentation using yaml/json configuration files?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, yaml, swagger-2.0

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class YamlSwaggerConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public SwaggerResourcesProvider swaggerResourcesProvider() {
        return () -> {
            List<SwaggerResource> resources = new ArrayList<>();
            Arrays.asList("api1", "api2", "api3").forEach(resourceName -> resources.add(loadResource(resourceName)));
            return resources;
        };
    }

    private SwaggerResource loadResource(String resource) {
        SwaggerResource wsResource = new SwaggerResource();
        wsResource.setName(resource);
        wsResource.setSwaggerVersion("2.0");
        wsResource.setLocation("/swagger-apis/" + resource + "/swagger.yaml");
        return wsResource;
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket swagger() {
        return new Docket(SWAGGER_2).select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any()).paths(PathSelectors.any()).build();
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {
    public static final String[] PUBLIC_URLS = { "/swagger-ui.html/**", "/v2/api-docs", "/swagger-resources/**"
            , "/webjars/**", "/v3/api-docs", "/googledocs/**" ,"/swagger-apis/**"};

    @Autowired
    private JwtFilter jwtFilter;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

//  @Bean
//  public HttpTransport httpTransport() {
//      return new NetHttpTransport();
//  }

    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        return new ModelMapper();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new CustomEmployeeDetailService();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(PUBLIC_URLS).permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
```

"http://localhost:8082/swagger-ui.html?urls.primaryName=api2" This Url Works Well Without Spring Security But With Spring Security ,
I Am Trying To Give Access To "http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html?urls.primaryName=api2" as above but i got "Not Found http://localhost:8080/swagger-apis/api1/swagger.yaml" So How To Solve It?,
In My Spring Boot Project Swagger.yaml files in Folder Like
"src/main/resource/static/swagger-apis/api1/swagger.yaml".

Answer (score -1):

```
public static final String[] PUBLIC_URLS = {"/employee/add","/employee/register","/employee/login", "/swagger-ui.html/**", "/v2/api-docs", "/swagger-resources/**"
        , "/webjars/**", "/v3/api-docs", "/googledocs/**" ,"/swagger-apis/**"};
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(PUBLIC_URLS).permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();

    http.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    return http.build();
}
@Configuration
```

@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

```
@Bean
public Docket apiDocket() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2);
}

@Primary
@Bean
public SwaggerResourcesProvider swaggerResourcesProvider(
        InMemorySwaggerResourcesProvider defaultResourcesProvider) {
    return () -> {
        List<SwaggerResource> resources = new ArrayList<>();
        Arrays.asList("api1", "api2", "api3").forEach(resourceName -> resources.add(loadResource(resourceName)));
        return resources;
    };
}

private SwaggerResource loadResource(String resource) {
    SwaggerResource wsResource = new SwaggerResource();
    wsResource.setName(resource);
    wsResource.setSwaggerVersion("2.0");
    wsResource.setLocation("/swagger-apis/" + resource + "/swagger.yaml");
    return wsResource;
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/swagger-apis/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/swagger-apis/")
    .setCachePeriod(0);
}
```

}